# Android button error

Tags: android, button

I made an app with three buttons. one makes a call, one sends an email and the third sends an sms. after making it the first time, i noticed the email button not responding. i tried to find an eroor but  couldnt. so i switched the code so that the email button sends an sms and the sms button sends an email. once again the email button which is now supposed to send an sms, doesnt respond. any ideas?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ContactDaveActivity extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}

public void buttonhandler(View view)
{
    switch(view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
    {
        try {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:xxxxxxxxxx"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException activtyException)
        {
            Throwable e = null;
            Log.e("dialingexample", "Call failed", e);
        }
        break;
    }
    case R.id.button2:
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain"); 
        String s = "xyz@gmail.com";
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{s });
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        break;

    }
    case R.id.button3:
    {
        String phoneNumber = "+xxxxxxxx";
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android -dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+phoneNumber));
        startActivity(smsIntent);
        break;
    }

}
```

}
}

Comment: ooops. sorry. i just forgot to add android:onClick in main.xml

Answer (score 1):

you have `android:onClick="buttonhandler"` in your main.xml file ?

and also check for all,button1,button2,button3

```
<Button android:id="@id/button1" android:onClick="buttonhandler" ... />

<Button android:id="@id/button2" android:onClick="buttonhandler" ... />

<Button android:id="@id/button3" android:onClick="buttonhandler" ... />
```